# The use of yii models

Tags: php, yii, model

Is it a good idea to use yii model with relations when we have relational queries to make everytime??

For example i have these tables:

- User
- Article
- ArticleVotes
- Category

> User is linked to Article and Article Votes
>
> Article and Article Votes are linked
>
> and Category and Article are linked...

so now to obtain these data i created a function which will return me an array of these table data which are related

```
function getArticles($limit)
{
    $criteria = new CDbCriteria();
    $criteria->limit = $limit;
    $articles = Article::model()->with('idCategory', 'idUser', 'idArticleVotes')->findAll($criteria);

    return array(
        'category' => $articles->idCategory, // object of type category
        'articles' => $articles, //object of type article
        'votes' => $articles->idArticleVotes, //object of type ArticleVotes which has other object of type users
        'user' => $articles->idUser, //object of type user
    );
}
```

is this code above a good way of using yii? specially if i have lots of data to retrieve from database???

will it be slow to execute???

Comment: I noticed you are returning the actual collumn values of the table 'Article' and not the 'object of type' as with your code above.  Did you declare the relationship in your Article model and define the keys?

Comment: no its not the columns its the relations well iuts not copy and paste i just wrote this code i know it should have been idUser0 or idCategory0 like yii generate it for you...

Comment: Avoid loading multiple one-to-many relations in one query. Doing so causes a *huge* number of rows to be returned. Look at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17133519/yii-eager-loading-fatal-error-out-of-memory/) for a solution.

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT:**
If you have over 20 articles or so per page, then I would definitely not create objects for every attribute of the article.  Here is a few tips and an answer I previously wrote is linked:

- Keep relations defined in your model for the case that you have
  single article look-ups or quick manipulation edits.
- You will need to create an efficient SQL look-up and push it directly using Yii::app()->db->command('sqlstatementhere') to pull out information in a batch of the set of article_ids.
- You will then parse your result (given in an array) to your page.
- When a user clicks on article to go to the ***single*** article page, you can use your standard models to retrieve the information.

Please refer to accepted answer here for clarification on DB and Yii
[Using Database Features of Yii](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14714781/using-the-database-features-of-the-yii-framework/15057069#15057069)

---

Quick answer: **perfectly ok!**

Your concern should not be Yii, it should be your DB structure / look-up time.

- Yii does not re-invent the wheel with linked models: aka it will use
  the article_id to do separate table look-ups, just as you would
  without using the link structure.
- The only time you think about staying away from links altogether is
  in batch look-ups and updates, where you would feed in more direct
  SQL statements to improve database load

*I have worked with Yii extensively with websites with over 200K page views a day.  With over 200 tables per DB to manage. I will tell you that taking advantage of a DB framework for table relations will make your code a blessing to manage.*

Comment: are you sure its PERFECTLY OK???? would it not be slow when i have to execute this query?? my database will not be too overloaded? for example if i execute this function in my controller and pass to my view
getArticles(); //this will take ALL articles in my db and return me the array of objects
and if i have like 100 records to fetch???
and normally the user table is a very big table everywhere.

Comment: you're absolutely right, For some reason i assumed it was looking up 1 article.  Please look at edit above.

Comment: this helped me a lot... i created this only for retrieving the data from db... so i will not be using these objects to modify db just retrieving them to display.

and in my tables im taking only other tables which (BELONGS_TO) do you think i can now take more data???

Comment: of course, retrieving data in using the dbcommand is the lowest form of database interaction and the result is a PHP array.  The most efficient method of extracting data with the lowest memory usage.  Please accept the answer if I was of help, many thanks!

Comment: yes this helped me a lot indeed. what i mean in my last comment was for the method i was currently using... will it be slow if i am retrieving many records but the relations are only (BELONGS_TO)??
the guys at my company are against cdbcommand, we can use cdbcriteria and models